# Separate within range in BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, function, google-bigquery

I have the following Input SQL table in BigQuery:

```
USER    code     created_day   created_time      unix_time   
4q7C0o  1358701  2019-09-30     10:49:26         1569840566
4q7C0o  1358701  2019-09-30     10:49:27         1569840567     
4q7C0o  1358701  2019-09-30     10:49:32         1569840567     
4q7C0o  1358701  2019-09-30     16:04:41         1569859481     
4q7C0o  1358701  2019-09-30     16:04:48         1569859489
4q7C0o  1358801  2019-09-30     16:28:28         1569860908
xEGXZQ  1438955  2019-09-30     11:28:00         1569850000
```

I would like to identify each subdivision in a code given by a certain range (in my case it would be to give a group id to each unix_time in a code ), so I have an output table similar to this :

```
USER    code         created_day   created_time       unix_time    code_block_id
4q7C0o  1358701       2019-09-30     10:49:26        1569840566         1
4q7C0o  1358701       2019-09-30     10:49:27        1569840567         1
4q7C0o  1358701       2019-09-30     10:49:32        1569840567         1
4q7C0o  1358701       2019-09-30     16:04:41        1569859481         2
4q7C0o  1358701       2019-09-30     16:04:48        1569859489         2
4q7C0o  1358801       2019-09-30     16:28:28        1569860908         1
xEGXZQ  1438955       2019-09-30     11:28:00        1569850000         1
```

Where the `code_block_id` is to identify/group each set of transactions in a code (ex. the first three rows belong to `code_block_id = 1` because the maximum amount of unix_time between the 1st row and 3rd does not exceed 300 seconds, however the 4th and 5th rows although they belong to the code `1358701` they are out of range of the unix_time + 300 of the first row. However the 4th and 5th row they do belong to `code_block_id = 2` because they are close together in unix_time) .

Comment: Clarify what is initial data and what is expected output

Comment: The initial data would be the final part `all_time_data_extended` which would be similar to the initial table that I described at the beginning. The expected output would be the second table at the beginning

Comment: i still didn't get what exactly your input data and expected output. and obviously I am not going to reverse engineer those for you! rather you should do you work so then we can help you. I think others who potentially would answer the question - feel same way

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to split table to partitions by `code` value and inside each partition you want dynamic subpartitions over ordering by `unix_time` where the initial row of each subpartition is the first one whose distance from initial row of previous subpartition is greater than 300 seconds.

For SQL engine without recursive queries, which is BQ, this is pretty hard problem. Transactions may come in arbitrary time and any info about transaction does not give any hint about subsequent transaction. Another code block depends on previous, it can hardly be computed somehow in advance. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59006588/653539) is about very similar problem, accepted solution is very elegant (way more than mine :-), unfortunately both responders didn't find any solution without recursive query.

Isn't some of following alternative solutions suitable for you?

- changing db vendor
- using stored procedures
- rethinking the way of identifying transactions (adding column with some session / correlation id would make your task trivial and result could also be more precise since with `unix_time` two transactions in range 300 s appear as single code block)